# Why was this character so quick to decide on murder?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, analysis, virata-parvam

At the end of the 2022 Netflix movie *Virata Parvam*,

> Ravanna shoots Vennela dead.

They both loved each other, but she did not think twice before shooting her.

Why did this happen?